# Neo4j error - Payload does not seem to be valid data

Tags: neo4j

I'm using the Neo4j browser to test the REST API like so:

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit {"statements":[ {"statement":"MATCH (n {name: "test"}) RETURN n"}]}
```

which gives an error:

> Payload does not seem to be valid data (Request payload error)

However, this same cypher query works fine without the REST syntax:

```
MATCH (n {name: "test"}) RETURN n
```

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attention to the **"**. Your are using it twice. Use **'** instead.

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit 
{"statements":[ {"statement":"MATCH (n {name: 'test'}) RETURN n"}]}
```